# Load fonts on Ruby Shoes

Tags: ruby, shoes

How would I go about loading a .ttf file on my Shoes app and set that as my default font?

Shoes version is 3.3.7

The documentation from http://shoesrb.com/manual/Built-in.html and http://shoesrb.com/manual/Styles.html mention font sections but dont mention an example of loading fonts.

Instead of installing the ttf file manually, I would like to know possible methods I could use to bundle and load it in Shoes (shy).

Something like below would be helpful.

```
font('./fontfile.ttf')
```

I would also like to avoid calling the font for each para individual ly. A workaround for that would be helpful too.

Sorry about this, I'm pretty new to programming.

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer if you link to said documentation and explain exactly what is unclear about it. You've obviously done some research on this topic; how about you share it? And how about saying what version of Shoes you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following in Shoes3, for example:

```
font 'relative/path/to/fonts/Arial.ttf' unless Shoes::FONTS.include?('Arial')
Shoes.app do
  ...
end
```

This example exists in the [Shoes3 source](https://github.com/shoes/shoes3/blob/e2ffb4e12e5e44759cb83c1ec4123e2c88cd6ab7/lib/shoes.rb#L149-L181).